# What is the purpose of having two different HitBuilders ( Social and Event)?

Tags: android, android-activity, google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-firebase

I am using google analytics for my application. I am using HitBuilder() to get the event hits and SocialBuilder() for social button hits.

Method For Social Button Hits

```
 public void sendGoogleAnalyticsSocialInteractionWithTarget(String SocialNetworkName,String SocialAction,String SocialTarget)
        {       
            dataTracker.send( new HitBuilders.SocialBuilder()                
                                            .setNetwork(SocialNetworkName) 
                                            .setAction(SocialAction)       
                                            .setTarget(SocialTarget)      
                                            .build());
        }
```

Method For Events Hit

```
  public void sendGoogleAnalyticsHitEvents(String category,String action,String label)
        {       
            dataTracker.send(new HitBuilders.EventBuilder()         
                                            .setCategory(category) 
                                            .setAction(action)   
                                            .setLabel(label)     
                                            .build());
        }
```

Except getting the hits details and count in different category,is there any other purpose for different HitBuilders?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its the way the data model is created for Google Analytics.

Events, Transactions, Pageviews, Social, AdWords are different data tables, with some related keys between them.  In practice, this means that there are some of the more obscure dimensions/metric combinations that won't work.

Comment: Yes,there will be different data tables.But i have found that the event builder is more useful than social builder to analysis tracked data. Thank you for reply.

Comment: Yep, I agree Events are generally more useful, and can be used instead - although it doesn't hurt to send to Social in case you need it in the future.  The multi-touch reports for example may be useful.

Comment: Ya.I have done the same,multi-touch reports to track hits. It tracks both in Event and Social. Let see how it behaves.

Answer (score 2):

The main reason for having different hit builders in GA to get the data in different categories. You can customize your data matrix in Customization section.